# I am trying to code in python 3.9+ to make an excel sheet comparison program based on dictionary values, their changes and their absences

Tags: python, excel, for-loop

In my code, you enter two different excel sheets and enter two column names (in a separate UI window), which is a part number column, and then a designator column. The code is designed to take these columns, turn them into a dictionary, and then see two things. If there are any designators under a different key from the original one, then display that in a new text window. Additionally, check the code if there are any values that are not present in either list, then also display that in the new window under a different section. The largest problem is the fact that oftentimes, the values show up as incorrect or just end up not showing up at all. Especially when I end up inputting larger excel sheets, the algorithm just does not function correctly.

I solicited the help of OpenAI, as I wanted to see if AI could help me see any logic or functional problems I was not seeing.

Here is my solution, which gives the correct outlier output, but does not enter the correct movements values at all.

```
dictxl1= create_dict(newListPNxl1,newListDesxl1)
    dictxl2= create_dict(newListPNxl2,newListDesxl2)
    commonDes=[]
    commmonPN=[]
    dict1= {key: values for key, values in dictxl1.items() if values }
    for i in newListDesxl1:
        index=0
        for e in newListDesxl2:
            sim= compare_similarity(i,e)
            if sim>99:
                commonDes.append(i)
                index= newListDesxl1.index(i)
                commonPN.append(newListPNxl1[index])
                break
    commonDict= create_dict(meepPN,meepDes)
    outDes=[]
    outPN=[]
    dict1= {key: values for key, values in dictxl1.items() if compare_similarity(values, commonDict.values())<99 }

    for value, key in dictxl1.items(): 
        for value2, key2 in commonDict.items():
            keyS=compare_similarity(key,key2)
            valueS=compare_similarity(value,value2)
            if (keyS<99):       
                if (valueS>99):          
                    outDes.append(value)
                    outPN.append(key)
                    break
    for value, key in dictxl2.items(): 
        for value2, key2 in commonDict.items():
            keyS=compare_similarity(key,key2)
            valueS=compare_similarity(value,value2)
            if (keyS<99):       
                if (valueS>99):          
                    outDes.append(value)
                    outPN.append(key)
                    break
    movedDes=[]
    movedPN=[]
    for key, value in dictxl2.items():
        for key2, value2, in dictxl1.items():
            keyS=compare_similarity(key,key2)
            valueS=compare_similarity(value,value2)
            if (keyS<99 and valueS>99): 
                movedDes.append(value)
                movedPN.append(key)
                break
```

The solution code that OpenAI gave me was this.

```
dict1 = create_dict(newListPNxl1, newListDesxl1)
    dict2 = create_dict(newListPNxl2, newListDesxl2)
    absent_values_dict = {}
    common_values_dict = {}
    dict2_values_set = set(dict2.values())
    dict1_values_set = set(dict1.values())
 
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        if value not in dict2_values_set:
            absent_values_dict[key] = value

    for key, value in dict1.items():
        if value in dict2_values_set and key != next((k for k, v in dict2.items() if v == value), None):
            common_values_dict[key] = (value, next((k for k, v in dict2.items() if v == value)))

    for key, value in dict2.items():
        if value not in dict1_values_set and value not in absent_values_dict.values() and value not in common_values_dict.values():
            absent_values_dict[key] = value
```

Is there any logical problem that I am not seeing, or anything that am doing wrong from what you can see?